# Rails export csv model with many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, model-associations

Hello i am new in Ruby on Rails and i have a little problem. I'm trying to export the data ***Recibo*** model in csv file. but this model model has associated the ***Atencion*** model.
I need the ***Recibo*** with all ***servicio_ids***
Thanks!

Model ***Recibo***

```
class Recibo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :caja_id, 
  :doctor_id, 
  :numero_recibo, 
  :paciente, 
  :total,
  :total_porcentaje_doctor,
  :total_porcentaje_clinica,
  :total_porcentaje_laboratorio, 
  :servicio_ids,
  :created_at,
  :updated_at

  belongs_to :caja
  belongs_to :doctor

  has_many :atencions
  has_many :servicios, :through => :atencions

  before_save do
    servicio_by_id = Servicio.where(:id => servicio_ids)

    self.total = servicio_by_id.sum(&:precio)

    self.total_porcentaje_doctor = servicio_by_id.sum ('porcentaje_doctor / 100.0 * precio')
    self.total_porcentaje_clinica = servicio_by_id.sum ('porcentaje_clinica / 100.0 * precio')
    self.total_porcentaje_laboratorio = servicio_by_id.sum ('porcentaje_laboratorio / 100.0 * precio')

  end

  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |recibo|
        csv << recibo.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      recibo = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      recibo.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      recibo.save!
    end
  end

end
```

Model Atencion

```
class Atencion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :recibo_id, 
  :servicio_id

  belongs_to :recibo
  belongs_to :servicio
end
```

The only column that not show is servicio_ids. Help me Please!

Answer (score 0):

try recibo.atencions.map(&:servicio_id)

recibo.atencions ==> will get all the atencions associated to the particular recibo
map(&:servicio_id) ==> will get all the servicio_ids in the associated atencions

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my solution!

```
  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["id", "caja_id", "doctor_id", "numero_recibo", "paciente", "total", "total_porcentaje_laboratorio",
        "total_porcentaje_clinica", "total_porcentaje_doctor", "created_at", "updated_at", "servicio_ids" ]
      all.each do |recibo|
        recibo.atencions.map(&:servicio_id)
        csv << [recibo.id, recibo.caja_id, recibo.doctor_id, recibo.numero_recibo,
          recibo.paciente, recibo.total, recibo.total_porcentaje_laboratorio, recibo.total_porcentaje_clinica, 
          recibo.total_porcentaje_doctor, recibo.created_at, recibo.updated_at, recibo.servicio_ids]
      end
    end
  end
```